# C#: Default Value for Constructor with Array Argument

Tags: c#, constructor, default-value

Hi C# experts out there

I have the following C# constructor which all have default values but I cannot figure out a way to set a meaningful default value for the `double[] signal` parameter:

```
public Raw(double amplitude = 10.0, ulong start = 0ul, ulong end = 10ul, double[] signal = null) : base(amplitude, start, end)
{
    if (signal == null)
    {
       this.Signal = new double[0];
    } else
    {
       this.Signal = signal;
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to use anything else besides `null`? What I actually want is an empty array like I do currently in the constructor's body. If I use `new double[0]` as default value the compiler complains that the parameter value must be compile-time constant. Any other approach to solve the above-shown scenario besides my current approach?

Thanks in advance for your support :)

Comment: Why don’t you just provide a method overload without that parameter?

Comment: BTW, your ctor code can be simplified: `this.Signal = signal ?? new double[0];`

Comment: default parameter value of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null

Comment: ok thanks for the info :)